# Flutter compute method and filter results in json

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I'm a really fresh new dev in flutter, I'm trying to filter results in a json response based on the title.
And i would like to use the compute method. This method only allow 2 arguments, so it's why i think i need to use a map to get the response.body and the query for filtering.

This is my HttpService :

```
class HttpService {
  
  static List<Post> _parsePosts(Map map) {
    print(map);

    return map["body"].map((json) => Post.fromJson(json)).where((post) {
      final titleLower = post.title.toLowerCase();
      final queryLower = map["query"].toLowerCase();
      return titleLower.contains(queryLower);

    }).toList();
  }

  static Future<List<Post>> fetchPosts(String query) async {
    final uri = Uri.parse('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
    final response = await retry(    
      () => http.get(uri).timeout(Duration(seconds: 10)),    
      retryIf: (e) => e is SocketException || e is TimeoutException,
    );

    Map posts = new Map();
    
    posts["body"] = json.decode(response.body);
    posts["query"] = query;

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return compute(_parsePosts, posts);
    } else {
      
      throw Exception("Failed to load posts ${response.statusCode}");
    }
  }

}
```

The print(map); contains the map with values -> https://prnt.sc/131ldey

But the problem is reported on : `return map["body"].map((json) => Post.fromJson(json)).where((post) {`

with : `_TypeError (type '(dynamic) => dynamic' is not a subtype of type '(dynamic) => bool' of 'test')`

I really don't understand what is the reason of this error..

Answer (score -1):

Your titleLower is not casted into a String type! So the contains method returns a dynamic value since it does not appear as the contains method of the String type for the VM !

```
final String myValue = ...;
return myValue.contains(‘a’);
```

Comment: Thanks for your pupose, it seems to fix this bug, but another appears at toList() : TypeError (type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Post>')
I tried to set "map["body"].map<Post>((json)" but producing the same

Comment: Are you sure the issue comes from there? Does it not come from the return compute ? Try specifying the type of the compute method (compute<Map, List<Post>> )

Comment: And since my answer worked out for you could you please accept it :)

Comment: Specifying the type of the compute method doesn't change anything : https://prnt.sc/131mjhp
I will accept as soon as errors are fixed, they are all related to the same method

Comment: Fair enough, what if you do store the value you return inside a Strongly type variable and then return that same variable?

Comment: If you think that you know the response update the answer to avoid a dicussion in comments